# Как вывести тэги под записью в блоге друпала

Tags: drupal

как вывести тэги под записью в блоге друпала

Answer (score 2):

если у вас друпал 7 , то просто добавьте к типу материала поле  taxonomy term reference

Comment: да, семёрка, извините, я с ним недавно работаю, а можно чуть подробенее описать

Comment: открываете страницу /admin/structure/types/manage/articles/fields , где articles - тип материала и добавляете поле "ссылка на термин"

Comment: Я добавлял такую штуку, дело в том что там можно только 1 артикл ввести, а не несколько
если я конечно правильно понял, Field - Term reference, там даёт выбрать на Autocomplete term widget (tagging) как тут #cars #car http://www.dc-lm.com/chto-za-bred

Comment: так потому что нужно добавить теги вначале материалам на странице их редактирования или добавления

Comment: не совсем вас понял..

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. Вы же добавляете эти теги к статьям, когда редактируете или пишете материалы. В редактировании типа материала (управление полями) у вас должно быть добавлено поле tags(ссылка на термин), и через это поле можно привязать свой материал к уже существующему термину таксономии, или добавить в словарь новый термин, связанный с материалом. А в управлении отображением нужно сделать это поле видимым. Все , в том месте куда вы решите выводить это поле оно и появится со списком терминов (тегов) привязанных к этой статье, по клику по которым вывалятся все материалы связанные с термином.
Если вам надо вывести теги с какими нибудь "извращениями", ну картинки там прикрутить к терминам или еще что нибудь, используйте модуль views. Там предусмотрена возможность вывода терминов таксономии.

Answer (score -1):

Можно изменить рендеринг тэгов по умолчанию, добавив следующий код в нижнюю часть файла style.css.

```
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference .field-item {display: inline; margin-right: 10px;}
```

Comment: http://www.dc-lm.com/blog/
боюсь вы меня не совсем поняли, вот есть сайт с блогом, и там нужно вывести под каждой записью теги, и соответственно, каждый тег это ссылка на группу постов объеденённых одним тегом - просто я уверен что есть какой то модуль для этого (может я его даже установил но не смог настроить), я просмотрел весь иностранный гугл, но ответа так и не нашёл